# I'm trying to run a block of codes in php & mysql to generate excel file(.xlsx) using PHPExcel. I've got error while running this code in sever

Tags: phpexcel

Please help me to solve this problem to identify error in this code I shall be greatful to you.
Here is my code

`

```
<?php

require_once('../_inc/dbConnect.php');
//echo "i";
require('PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php');
//echo "i1";

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$rowCount = 1;
//echo $rowCount;
//echo "i";
$query = "select * from M_FARMER_DETAILS";  
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, $row['F_NAME']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $row['F_ADDRESS']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $row['F_MOBILE']);   
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.$rowCount, $row['F_AADHAR']);
    $rowCount++;
}
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save('some_excel_file.xlsx');
*/
?>`
```

Comment: */ what's with this part at the bottom?

Comment: ignore that please

Comment: So what error do you get?

Comment: "is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"

Comment: There's a couple of things I would do to troubleshoot, one would be to add an if statement in the while loop and break if$rowCount >10  . Or comment out the bottom line, then run, then the second bottom line, and keep doing this until it runs. Then you'll find out which part is buggy.